# How to get instance variables after running class method in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I will like to inquire how to get instance variables after running class methods in Python 3. Here is my code sample;

```
class item:
    def __init__(self,code,name,price,qty):
        self.code=code
        self.price=price
        self.name=name
        self.qty=qty

    def blow(self):
        nan = self.code + self.price
        return nan

o = item(1121,'we',340,2)
o_blow = o.blow()

# Print o_blow
print(o_blow)
```

After printing `o_blow`, it returns

`1461`

My question is, how can I get the value of `self.name` from the `o_blow` variable? Is there a way I can get the value of `self.name` ('we') that was used to instantiate the class from the `o_blow` variable?

I tried `o_blow.name` but it returned this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(o_blow.name)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: You can't. If you need data in an object, you need access to the object. In this case, you need `o.name`.

Comment: Yeah that's right! I know i can get it from ```o.name``` but I was wondering if there is a way I can also get it from the new variable ```o_blow```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be

```py
o.name
```

Your function returns an `int`, not an instance of `item` (let alone `o`). Therefore you cannot get name from it. You could return `self` and it will behave as you want.

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self,code,name,price,qty):
        self.code=code
        self.price=price
        self.name=name
        self.qty=qty

    def blow(self):
        self.nan = self.code + self.price
        return self

o = Item(1121,'we',340,2)
o_blow = o.blow()

# Print o_blow
print(o_blow.nan) # nan value
print(o_blow.name) # name
```

Comment: Thanks, that's right! I know I can get ```self.name``` by running ```o.name``` but I was wondering if i could also get it from the ```o_blow``` variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in errorlog o_blow type is int. It is new object which isn't connected to your class item, so you can't get the value of self.name.